# Problem in Run Time Environment in Eclipse Jee Oxyg

Tags: java, database, eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

I have a problem in Java Eclipse Oxygen.
The problem is that during the Run Time Environment all the Run time Environment is displayed in red coloured box.
I have a problem in solving that.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could post a picture of your _Eclipse_ with the red-colored box?

Comment: I'm new here so I have no idea how this website works. I couldn't post it. The website just sent me a pop up message that it is possible to upload pictures after you have earned 10 points.

Comment: upvoted your question and comment so that you can get enough rep to upload photo but sadly you're 1 rep short :(

Comment: See if there is anything written in the _Problems_ view. To display the _Problems_ view open the _Window_ menu then choose _Show View_ item and finally choose _Problems_

Comment: It's harmless. It just means there's a bug in how the adapters are packaged.

Comment: The problem got solved. I accidentally deleted the Jboss in the Eclipse application in the run time environment so the error occurred and the error got solved when I installed the Jboss runtime environment.